# add input text and rateit stars to table also jsfiddle javascript not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a row to a table with 2 cells.
cell 1: text from input field
cell 2: rateit star ratting
Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
<button type="button" id="cl" onclick="checkit()">Check I'm working</button>
</div>    
 <p><b> Please enter an item, rate it, and click <i>Add to Remedy</i>thanks</b></p> 
 <div class="form-group">
        <div>
     <label id="inp-title" class="control-label" for="formInput1">Field label</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="formInput1"  placeholder="Placeholder text">
 </input>
       </div>
       <div>
                <div id="rateit_id"  class="rrateit"></div>
      </div><br><br>
<button type="button" id="add-to-remedy" class="btn btn-default">Add to Remedy</button> 
<div>
    <table class="table" id="remedy-tbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Remedy Item</th>
                <th>Item Rating</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here's my JQuery:

```
     $( document ).ready(function() {
   var rate-val= 0; 
$('div#rateit_id').rateit();
  function checkit(){
          alert("HELLO WORLD!");
                    };

$("#rateit_id").click(function() {
    rate-val = ($(this).rateit('value'));
                   });                                 

$("#add-to-remedy").click(function()
  {  
  var htmlToAppend =                         
'<tr><td>' + $('input[type=text].form-control').val() + '</td><td>' +               
'<div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="' + rate-val +       
'" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true"></div>' + '</td></tr>';
      $("#remedy-tbl").append ( htmlToAppend );                   
      newTableRow.appendTo("#remedy-tbl");
            });
  });
```

and here's the jsFiddle that's not working http://jsfiddle.net/gZ9by/8/ I understand the problem is the javascript's not working, but I don't know why. Help with this would also be much appreciated.
Thanks
David

Comment: You can't use hyphens in variable names. JavaScript interprets this as subtraction.

Comment: What is newTableRow supposed to be?

Comment: I've fixed a bunch of it so far. You should really use your web browser's developer console to see the errors that are getting passed. Here's a fiddle to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/br85r/2/.

Comment: Thanks Jason, Any idea why the javascript's not working and why the rateit readonly doesn't appear in the table?

Comment: I se I've answered my own question, if the javascript's not working then I can't add it to the table!

Comment: The javascript appears to be working in my fiddle. The rateit readonly is being added to the table, but the rateit readonly elements only render when the page loads. I'm not sure how to dynamically add them. There is probably a rateit function for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your rateit function thats why preceding jquery is not working otherwise your code is good.

Answer (score 0):

OK - first I changed 'rate-val' to not use the subtraction sign (invalid JavaScript variable).  I also fixed some JavaScript errors.

In the section where you add the item to the table, you don't actually put the rateval variable into the div.  You put it in a custom data- binding, but not where it is actually displaying the HTML.

I updated it as follows:

```
$("#add-to-remedy").click(function () {
    var htmlToAppend =
        '<tr><td>' + $('input[type=text].form-control').val() + '</td><td>' +
        '<div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="' + rateval +
        '" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-readonly="true">' + rateval + '</div>' + '</td></tr>';
    $("#remedy-tbl").append(htmlToAppend);
    newTableRow.appendTo("#remedy-tbl");
});
```

An unknown from my perspective (due to not knowing the rateit framework) is what the data-rateit-value is supposed to do.  If it is supposed to automatically populate the div when you assign the data-rateit-value, then I do not know what should be fixed with it.   That said, I believe the following fiddle accomplishes what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/gZ9by/13/

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Laura. Jason did this  jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/br85r/2. There you can see rateit working. data-rateit-value is a value from 0 - 5 depending on how many stars are selected.

Comment: No problem - always great to learn something new!  That's one of the goal of me looking at things here...to help others and also learn from others